# Player rotation by using touch joystick not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I am developing this game for android where I need tow touch joysticks to move and look around and i have been able to do that with the script that I have now but I have a problem once I stop moving the joystick the player rotation reverts to its original position any Help?????

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody RB;
    public FixedJoystick Joystick;
    public Joystick Joystick2;
    public float MoveSpeed = 300f;
    public Vector3 LastPosition;
    public Vector3 frameMovement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        RB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        LookAround();

    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {

        RB.velocity = new Vector3(Joystick.Horizontal * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, RB.velocity.y, Joystick.Vertical * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void LookAround()
    {
        float horizontal = Joystick2.Vertical;
        float vertical = Joystick2.Horizontal;

        frameMovement = new Vector3(-horizontal, 0f, vertical);

        Quaternion rotation =
        Quaternion.LookRotation(frameMovement);
        RB.transform.rotation = rotation;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: At every frame, Unity uses the ```Update()``` method to function.
You're calling ```LookAround()```, which in turn uses ```Joystick2.Vertical``` and ```Joystick2.Horizontal```. If the user leaves the Joystick come to its initial position, I imagine these values become 0, and because the function is in ```Update()```, that means it will instantly get updated to a rotation of 0.

Comment: Can you suggest a solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I makes sense that the rotation comes back to default when you stop touching as it is in function of the Joysticks position and calle in an update. From your code:

```
float horizontal = Joystick2.Vertical;
float vertical = Joystick2.Horizontal;

frameMovement = new Vector3(-horizontal, 0f, vertical);
```

I would try to handle the `LookAround();` call with the [touchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) so that when you call the `LookAround()` only during the touch phase and not all of the time.

Comment: But would that solve the rotation reseting??

Comment: that is my suggestion. That is what I would try. If you handle that the `LookAround()` is only run when the joystick is touched, you can check if the last lookAt is kept by the camera. If it does not work, you can handle that keeping the rotation of the camera in a variable and re-setting it when the touching phase ends

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked!                                                                                                                                  public void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch(0).position.x > Screen.width / 2)
        {
            
                LookAround();
        }

    }

Comment: glad that helped ;)